# How to add event to input react

Tags: reactjs, dom-events

I'm using react to create a table that has draggable rows.
Those rows have inputs to change their props.
When I'm using `onChange={this.onchange(this.value)}` I get the following error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: React.PropTypes type checking code is stripped in production.

I should be able to use the `onChange` function on a element right?
I also got a warning that tells me so.

> You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field.

My full code can be found in this link:
[My code](https://codepen.io/darkinfore/pen/mvMQGB)

This is the code without onchange events to the inputs so you can see the result.
I want to add onchange events to the input fields and change the value inside the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the value prop on your inputs, but not giving it a method to actually handle the change.

To your input, add an `onChange` handler but **don't call it**.

`<input type="text" value={props.caption} onChange={this.handleChange}/>`

The `handleChange` function should look like this:

`handleChange = (e) => this.setState({something: e.target.value})`

It takes the event as an argument, and you access the input's value using `e.target.value`; Then you update the state with the new value, which should be bound to the input's `value` prop. This is called a controlled component, where you handle changes within React.

You can read more about controlled vs uncontrolled components here: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: Thanks, any chance you can implement this in my current code as example, I have no idea where to place it in my code

Comment: Can you please help me placing the function in my code?